# Can one of Windows failover cluster nodes run on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, clustering

As SQL Server is available for Linux can I configure Clustering on Linux nodes? I mean mixed with Windows - some nodes are on Linux, others on Windows in the same cluster?

Comment: Is there a reason why mirroring won't cut it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> As SQL Server is available for Linux can I configure Clustering on Linux nodes?

You can configure [Corosync](http://corosync.github.io/corosync/) and [pacemaker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/workloads/sap/high-availability-guide-suse-pacemaker) for Linux. Good luck.

> I mean mixed with Windows - some nodes are on Linux, others on Windows in the same cluster?

In the same cluster, no. Someone will argue with me and say, "Well, Sean, you can do read-scale availability groups like this!" and that may be true, however it isn't a cluster.

The only way to do this would be to have two different clusters, spanned by a distributed availability group. If you want to make life complicated then this would be the setup to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - cross platform is supported for AlwaysON availablity groups. Microsoft recommends to use this only for migration and not for HA.

See - [Configure SQL Server Always On Availability Group on Windows and Linux (cross-platform)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-availability-group-cross-platform?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Kin, it's not a cluster, hence `CLUSTER_TYPE = NONE` which means you're not going to get HA. This is a read-scale AG.

Comment: Yes agreed. Just wanted to highlight that mostly it can be used for read-scale or for migration (which I am going to use it to migrate from windows to Linux).